# Why I am able to pass a bigger array into a smaller array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

This might be a silly question but does a Java array accept more than its size? If yes then why do we need ArrayList? I thought that arrays had a fixed size that can't be increased at runtime. Here is my test code:

```
public class ArraySizeDemo {
    int[] anArray = new int[5];

    public int[] getAnArray() {
        return anArray;
    }

    public void setAnArray(int[] anArray) {
        this.anArray = anArray;
    }
}

public class ArrayDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArraySizeDemo ar = new ArraySizeDemo();

        int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int testarray[] = new int[10];
        ar.setAnArray(arr); // it should give an error here since I am trying to 
        // assign an array of 10 to an array of 5
        testarray = ar.getAnArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            System.out.println(testarray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should accept one if it is helpful

Answer (score 19):

The assignment

```
this.anArray = anArray;
```

doesn't copy the elements of `anArray` to `this.anArray`.

It changes the value of the `this.anArray` variable to refer to the same array referenced by `anArray`. Therefore, before the assignment `this.anArray` refers to an array of length 5, and after the assignment it refers to a **different array object** of length 10.

If instead of this assignment you attempted to copy elements of the source array to the (smaller) target array, an exception would have been thrown, since the length of an array cannot be changed, so the elements of an array of length 10 cannot fit in an array of length 5.

Answer (score 7):

You are changing the reference of `this.anArray` doing `this.anArray = anArray;`.

After that assignment, `this.anArray` is a reference pointing to **another** array, the one of ten elements.

Answer (score 6):

You're not changing the array of 5.  You are replacing it entirely.

If your method looked like this, it would result in the error you expect:

```
public void setAnArray(int[] anArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
        this.anArray[i] = anArray[i];
    }
}
```

However, after you do it the following way, the array of 5 is literally thrown away, and replaced with the array of 10:

```
public void setAnArray(int[] anArray) {
    this.anArray = anArray;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Do not write a loop like that in real code.  Use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) instead.

Answer (score 1):

when you instate object of `ArraySizeDemo` => `ArraySizeDemo ar = new ArraySizeDemo();` what happened is something like this

```
Memory : 
-------------------------
...
anArray point to 0x100        
...  
-------------------------
```

and when create another array `int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`

```
Memory : 
-------------------------
...
anArray point to 0x111
arr     point to 0x222    
...  
-------------------------
```

and when call `ar.setAnArray(arr)` you're passing the reference of `arr` which is in are demo `0x222`

and in `setAnArray()` body you're changing the reference of `anArray` to the passed reference `this.anArray = anArray;`

so after calling `ar.setAnArray(arr)`

```
Memory : 
-------------------------
...
anArray point to 0x222
arr     point to 0x222    
...  
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the statement: `this.anArray = anArray`

or, in general any statement of type: `array[x] = array[y]`

does not copy element's of one array to another. The *assignment* operator, here, simply *references(provides location/address of)* one array to other.

A clear in-depth explanation about this is provided [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/09/copy-array.html) [(archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200531093811/http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/09/copy-array.html)